# dynamically add a user assigned managed identity to a function app during DevOps Deployment

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-managed-identity

I am creating ARM templates to deploy an azure function.
I can parameterize most things, but I am unable to parameterize UserAssignedManagedIdentities.

The value for a userAssignedManagedIdentity is not a value in the json ARM template, but is instead an object that contains the reference to the managed identity.

ARM does not allow parameterization in this instance.

I can hard code the reference to the managed identity but this is not ideal when deploying across multiple environments.

Is there a way to dynamically add a user assigned managed identity to a function app during Azure Devops Deployment?

[image]
*This does not work*

[image]
*This works*

Update: Adding more detail.

Below is the section of the template, parameterized, and the error that I get.

```
 "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
        "name": "[parameters('FunctionAppName')]",
        "location": "North Europe",
        "kind": "functionapp",
        "identity": {
          "type": "SystemAssigned, UserAssigned",
          "userAssignedIdentities": {
            
            "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('SubscriptionID'), '/resourcegroups/', parameters('ResourceGroup'),'/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/', parameters('UserAssignedManagedEntityName') ]": {}
          }
        },
        "properties": {
          "enabled": true,
          "hostNameSslStates": [
            {
              "name": "[concat(parameters('FunctionAppName'),'.azurewebsites.net')]",
              "sslState": "Disabled",
              "hostType": "Standard"
            },
```

Comment: curious if this will work [resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'test-identity')] where 'test-identity' is your identity.  I got this by creating a bicep template to get id of existing identity and this was in the generated ARM template.

Comment: ARM does allow for parameterization there - all 3 (Scott's suggestion) should work fine.  If you're still having trouble share the error you're getting and the code (the screenshot truncates stuff that could be important)

Comment: Good point, thanks.

Ive updated the main post with the parameterized version of the userAssignedIdentity and the error.

Comment: Please ignore, Ive been staring at this too long. It was a silly syntax issue.